# Authenticate using OAuth and AccountManager

Tags: android, oauth, accountmanager

I'm having problem authenticating using OAuth and YouTube. The retrieval of the auth token
goes fine but gdata.youtube.com claims that the auth key is invalid. I have re-generated the
key using invalidateAuthToken, so the key hasn't expired.

What am I missing out?

Choose Account

```
Intent intent = accountManager.getAccountManager().newChooseAccountIntent(
    null, 
    null, 
    new String[]{"com.google"}, 
    true, 
    null,
    AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE, 
    new String[] {"text"}, 
    null);

startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_AUTHENTICATE);
```

Retrieval of auth token.

```
Bundle options = new Bundle();
options.putString("client_id", "67674xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com");

accountManager.getAccountManager().getAuthToken(
    account, 
    AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE, 
    options, 
    (Activity)context, 
    accountManagerCallback, 
    null);
```

Http request

```
URL feedUrl = new URL(build_query(action, arguments));

final HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(feedUrl.toURI());
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();      
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

final DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

inputStream = timedCall(new Callable<InputStream>() {
    @Override
    public InputStream call() throws Exception {
            httpGet.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + authAccount.getActiveAccountAuthToken());
            httpGet.addHeader("X-GData-Key", "key=");   

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if(responseCode == 401) {
                response.getEntity().consumeContent();
                throw new AuthAccountException(responseCode);
            }
            return response.getEntity().getContent();
        }       
    },
    15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong scope. Instead of recieving the access token I recieved the client login token.
The correct scope for OAuth 2.0 is https://gdata.youtube.com